# How to find corner (x, y) coordinate points on image Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Canny Edge Detection]

This is a truck container image but from the top view. First, I need to find the rectangle and know each corner position. The goal is to know the dimension of the container.

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Comment: well i tried to remove unnecesary area by applying a ROI so there is only a square image, but i need to know the corner position.

Comment: Which rectangle, the outer rectangle or the inner one? Please post your code, to show what you have tried.

Comment: Post the original image from which you did the Canny edge detection. Perhaps another approach might be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load image](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html), convert to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html),
   [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Find distorted bounding rectangle contour and corners.** We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then filter using [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to isolate the rectangular contour. Next we find the distorted bounding rectangle with `cv2.minAreaRect()` and the corners with `cv2.boxPoints()`

---

Detected bounding rectangle `->` Mask `->` Detected corners

[image]
[image]
[image]

Corner points

```
(188, 351)
(47, 348)
(194, 32)
(53, 29)
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find distorted bounding rect
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 5000:
        # Find distorted bounding rect
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        corners = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        corners = np.int0(corners)
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [corners], (255,255,255))
        
        # Draw corner points
        corners = corners.tolist()
        print(corners)
        for corner in corners:
            x, y = corner
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (36,255,12), -1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Why using a corner detector (which is always difficult to tune) when you already know the corners ???

Comment: Wot you don't know the corner coordinates beforehand so use `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` to get the corner coordinates

Comment: Come on, `minAreaRect` !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Changed! Thanks for catching that unnecessary step

Answer (score 0):

`minAreaRect` applied to the contour is your best friend. There is no need for a corner detector.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9